# I can't find the name of this feature (application expansion packs for main application)

Tags: android

There are some Android applications that have expansion packs were the  users can download expansions that suit them separately from the app like this one

(the main app) https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dailyyoga.inc

(the expansion or whatever they are called) https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dailyyoga.tranquility/

what are they called in android I tried the word package, expansion packs but with no luck until now, am I searching for the wrong word here, are they a separate android application.

Answer (score 0):

They are called expansion packs? Simply the developer uses packageManager to access the extension app (usually when an in-app purshase made)

```
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
List<PackageInfo> packages = pm.getInstalledPackages();
for(PackageInfo package : packages) {
    if(package.packageName.startWith("com.pack.extension.") {
        // download package etc.
        handleExtensionPackage(package);
    }
}
```